# PHP underfined variable - table within mysql database

Tags: php, variables, mysqli, code-injection

I receive the following error message:

Notice: Undefined variable: db_table in /path/mailDB.php on line 58 
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli_db in on line 59 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /path/mailDB.php on line 59

Please can someone tell me what I have done wrong?
The code to correct this error?
And if I have binded correctly to prevent SQL code injection?

```
<?php

//Main Code Sequence
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

//Database Setup    
$db_host = "www.***";
$db_name = "***";
$db_table = "emailUser";
$db_username = "***";
$db_password = "***";
$mysqli_db = new mysqli($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name);

function webmailSignUp()
{
    $webmailFullName = $_POST['webmailFullName'];
    $webmailUserName = $_POST['webmailUserName'];
    $webmailExEmail = $_POST['webmailExEmail'];
    $webmailPhone = $_POST['webmailPhone'];
    $webmailDOB = $_POST['webmailDOB'];

    //Check that the fields are not empty
    if ((!empty($webmailFullName)) or (!empty($webmailUserName)) or (!empty($webmailExEmail)) or (!empty($webmailPhone)) or (!empty($webmailDOB)))
    {
        //Check that there is no existing name in the table
        if (checkUser($webmailUserName) == false)
        {
            //Adding the person to the Database Query   
            $query = "INSERT INTO $db_table(userFullName,userName,userExEmail,userPhone,userDOB) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
            //Binding to Prevent SQL injection                      
            $requery = $mysqli_db->prepare($query);
            $requiry->bind_param($webmailFullName,$webmailUserName,$webmailExEmail,$webmailPhone,$webmailDOB);
            if ($requery->execute())
            {
                echo "Person has been added";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "bind failed";
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            echo "There is already a user registered with this username.  Please try a different one.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "One of your fields are blank!  Please try again";
    }
}

function checkUser($userNameCheck)
{
    //Check the field userName is the same as the Posted Username
    $Field = "userName"; //The Field to check
    $query = "SELECT $Field WHERE $Field=$userNameCheck FROM $db_table LIMIT 1"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($query, $mysqli_db) or die(mysql_error());

    if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error()))
    {
        return false; //username was not found in the field in the table
    }
    else
    {
        return true; //username was found in the field in the table
    }
}

function db_close()
{
    $mysqli_db->close();
}

if(isset($_POST['webmailRegisterSubmit']))
{
    webmailSignUp();
    db_close();
    echo "End of Registration";
}
if(isset($_POST['webamilForgottenPWSubmit']))
{
    webmailForgottenPassword();
    db_close();
    echo "End of Password Reset Request";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at the [scope of variables in PHP](http://php.net/language.variables.scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in `$mysqli_db` as a parameter to checkUser or make it a global.

Currently `$mysqli_db` is undefined inside the function. This applies to any function where you need to use `$mysqli_db`.

Like this:

```
function checkUser($userNameCheck)
{
    global $mysqli_db;
```

Or:

```
function checkUser( $userNameCheck, $mysqli_db ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

> Notice: Undefined variable: db_table in /path/mailDB.php on line 58 Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli_db in on line 59 Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /path/mailDB.php on line 59

`$mysqli_db` is not available inside your function, it is [out of scope](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Pass that variable to your function

```
function webmailSignUp($mysqli_db){
```

then call like

```
 webmailSignUp($mysqli_db);
```

Same for other functions that want to use that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You also mixed up the two params:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query, $mysqli_db) or die(mysql_error());
```

instead of

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_db, $query) or die(mysql_error());
```

From php.net:

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

Procedural style

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

Try to change to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_db, $query) or die(mysql_error());
```